# How to pass an Array of GUIDs to Dapper/MySQL as parameter?

Tags: c#, mysql, f#, mariadb, dapper

I have a table that the `ID` field is a `GUID` stored in binray form.
Now i need to pass an array of `GUID`s to the MySQL to perform the bellow query:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `ID` IN (...`GUIDs in Binary Form`...);
```

However, the MySqlConnector seems to not support an array of byte arrays (`Byte[][]`) and Dapper can not convert this type of parameter.

I'm using a custom function to convert `GUID` type to `Byte[]`.
Is there any way to do the above query in Dapper?

Comment: Convert your array of bytes to the string of HEX codes ('0' -> '30', 'A' -> '41' and so on, no starting '0x') and provide it to MySQL. Use `UNHEX()` in the query to revert back to binary if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), you can set the [`GuidFormat`](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#GuidFormat) connection string option to `Binary16`, `LittleEndianBinary16`, or `TimeSwapBinary16` to match how your application code is converting `Guid` to byte arrays.

Then you can use [Dapper's list support](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/main/Readme.md#list-support) to pass an `IEnumerable<Guid>` or `Guid[]` as a parameter: Dapper will expand it to a list of individual `Guid` parameters and MySqlConnector will format them correctly as binary for your MySQL table.